# Python . Сделать так, чтоб, после первого вызова функции, ее больше нельзя было вызвать

Tags: python, функции, telebot

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот скриншот функции. Как сделать так, чтобы человек получив ответ от бота, не смог вызвать её еще раз и получить ответ снова?

Comment: Вообще-то предоставлять код скриншотом не лучшая практика... Сделайте глобальный флаг, потом после первого вызова изменяйте его, а в теле функции при вызове делайте проверку этого состояния флага.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исходя из того, что это бот и возможно скрипт запускается как функция только на время выполнения, я бы на вашем месте использовал любую БД как средство хранения состояния, а `chat_id` как первичный ключ для поиска, т.к. по сути он уникален.

Соответственно если есть какие-то этапы, то каждый этап помечать как пройденный или просто заполнять результатом ввода пользователя, соответственно, перед каждый выполнением функции, проверять выполнена эта функция ранее или нет.